# Looking for double transactions, but the date shall be different

Tags: sql, date

I wanna do database request, but I am not sure how to do it exactly.

```
select purpose, payee, iban, amount, booked_at, count(*)
from invoice_payments ip <
where purpose<>"" <
and created_at>"2019-07-01" <
and booked_at is !=
group by purpose having count(*)>1
order by 5 desc;
```

This is my code, but I wanna exclude transactions which have the same date. I have to solve that with booked_at, but I don't how to do.

Has somebody a guess?

Thank you

Comment: What defines a duplicate transaction, what columns needs to be equal?

Comment: what is "booked_at is !="?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using...

Answer (score 0):

if you have ID or any unique key your table `invoice_payments`  you can use this query.

```
select purpose, payee, iban, amount, booked_at, t2.ct
from invoice_payments t1
inner join
    (select ip.ID, count(1) as ct
    from invoice_payments ip 
    where purpose <> ''
        and created_at > '2019-07-01'   
    group by booked_at having count(1) = 1) as t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows where some columns are the same but dates are different, then use `exists`:

```
select purpose, payee, iban, amount, booked_at, count(*)
from invoice_payments ip
where exists (select 1
              from invoice_payments ip2
              where ip2.purpose = ip.purpose and
                    ip2.payee = ip.payee and
                    ip2.iban = ip.iban and
                    ip2.amount = ip.amount and
                    ip2.booked_at <> ip.booked_at
             );
```

It is unclear what defines a "duplicate".  This assumes that the first four columns define duplicates.